# Can i store sqlite db as zip file in iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, compression, zip

My sqlite file has a size of 7MB. I want to reduce its size. How i can do that ? When am simply compressing  it will come around only 1.2 MB. Can i compress my mydb.sqlite to a zip file ? If it is not possible, any other way to reduce size of my sqlite file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to compress before hand, but is very redundant.  You will compress your binary before distribution, Apple distributes your app through the store compressed and the compression of a compressed file is fruitless.  Thus, any work you do to compress beforehand should not have much of an effect on the resulted size of your application

Comment: indeed compressing an already compressed file can result in an increase in size.

Answer (score 1):

without details of what you are storing in the DB it's hard to give specific advice. The usual generics on DB Design will apply. Normalise your database.. for example

reduce/remove repeating data. If you have text/data that is repeated then store it once, and use key to reference it

If you are storing large chunks of data then you might be able to zip and unzip these in and out of the database in your app code rather than try to zip the DB